# CouchDB view query fails when a complex JSON is used as a key

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I have created a view on the db which emits key,value pair like so:

`emit([doc.some_key, doc.inner_doc], doc)`

Note that `doc.inner_doc` can be just any other JSON document.
Now, there is a problem while fetching records for such keys. Whenever the `doc.inner_doc` key exceeds more than 2 items, for eg. {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, the view query fails to give any result.

I am using [this](https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python) python library to work with couchdb. A query with a key like `[1, {"a":1, "b":2]` works perfectly but same is not the case with keys exceeding 2 items.

Any leads?

Comment: Just a little comment, never emit **doc** as a value since it will add the document into your index files. Instead, use the include_docs query parameter. I'll investigate your problem later today.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisCôté. I am actually emmiting `doc._id`. This was just an example.